# Can I cut and paste structured data in Browsers via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, html, clipboard

My users work with a dozen web applications. Over some I have complete control over others only limited via templates and Javascript (e.g. Zendesk).

Between these Applications I want my users to be able to copy and paste structured data. With structured date I mean for example an address encoded as vcard/hcard. So when somebody "copies" an address out of the "order processing application" and pastes it in the "new return shipment" application the return shipment application should be somehow able to receive the data not as a single large string but as "Name, Street, ZIP, City" in a datatructure.

I understand that Rich Text Editors can receive not only plaintext but also fully marked up text. Can this (order something else) be used to capture and/or recreate the structure of the copied data?

Comment: Seems like I'm looking for Microsofts ca. 2006 "Live Clipboard" IDea. See http://www.masternewmedia.org/news/2006/03/31/copy_structured_data_between_web.htm

Comment: Cutting via a click could be handled by something like http://github.com/mojombo/clippy cutting by moenu or keyboard and pasting could be handled by http://code.google.com/p/liveclipboard-jquery/ - beyond that it seems all do it yourself.

Comment: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/pastehandler.html is an example of clipboard access vie closure. http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/source/browse/trunk/ZeroClipboard10.as Shows how to use flash to put HTML in the clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize your data using JSON in one page, and deserialize it in the other.

```
{
    "Name" : "John Smith",
    "City" : "New York",
    "ZIP"  : "10281"
}
```

I suppose you could have button(s) called "Import" and "Export Data" and a field where you can copy and paste the JSON strings. This could be used in conjunction with clipboard manipulation (like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) does) to make the process more user friendly.